# Why do I need block dimension in order to calculate the thread ID in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I am new to CUDA and I have read about it and how to calculate the ID of the thread. I have a question about thread ID, as can be seen, for instance, in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvo3v.png).

What I don´t understand is why thread and block coordinates aren´t enough to calculate the threadID and instead I need to use the block dimensions.

Comment: The image actually shows it nicely. There are multiple threads for which `(threadIdx.x,threadIdx.y)` is `(1,2)`, for example. As pointed out by ApoorvaJ: In order to obtain **unique** indices, you also have to take into account in which *block* this thread is, and how many threads are in one block.

Answer (score 3):

As seen in the [CUDA documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#axzz4QeODhv33), multiple threads together form a block, and multiple such blocks form a grid.

Now, when each thread in the grid needs to be uniquely identified, you must factor in the block dimensions.

[image]

In the following example, `i` and `j` together uniquely identify each thread in the grid.

```
int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
```

`threadIdx` is the index of a thread within a block, and `blockIdx` is the index of a block within a grid. So you must have `blockDim` to get the unique indices `i, j` of a thread within the grid.

Comment: Ok, but I still have the same question. Why is `blockDim` necesary? Sorry I know maybe it is a silly question. It wouldn´t be ok to say: `int i = blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
int j = blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;`? This way I know the thread within a block and the block within a grid. Why do I need how many threads are there in a block (i.e. the block dimension)?

Comment: To uniquely identify each _thread_ within the entire _grid_. I suggest you attempt, on paper, to try the formula you stated and try to uniquely index each thread this way. I'm afraid I don't know how to explain this any further.

Answer (score 0):

We must really2 understand and can imagine, physical visualization in our head when kernel was launched and threads was created, and about what blockDim, blockIdx, threadIdx really mean....

Block dimension(BlockDim) is "NUMBER (count) of THREADS" in each BLOCK in X or Y or Z dimension (dependent of .X, .Y, or .Z).

BlockIdx.x represent index number which thread is locate in what block. Index number of block is counted from zero, ordered from left  to right (x), up down (y), front to back (z).

threadIdx.x is index locally start from zero in each block (blockIdx.x). 
But, we should know the "Global Index of thread" when it running/life. So it need:

```
    uint globalIdx_x = blockIdx.X * blockDim.X + threadIdx.x;
```

Try to read and learn from this book:
Professional CUDA C Programming -- Wrox Programming.